# Регулярное выражение на проверку длины

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть следующая регулярка которая проверяет номер телефона **`/373(\d{9})$/`**

Хочу еще добавить проверку на валидность операторского префикса, но он может состоять как из 2 цир так из 3, но на выходе нужно чтобы длина состояла из 9 цифр вместе с префиксом.

Пример `/373(44|447)(\d{9})$/`

Comment: Вы хотите жестко забить коды операторов?

Comment: Да, это условие самого оператора. Будет массив с перечисленными префиксами,

Comment: Я не знаю какие у вас существуют префиксы, но в данном случае префикс `447` неотличим от `44` при условии, что вам нужен номер телефона вместе с префиксом. `/373(44\d{7})$/`

Comment: Ну это я как пример привел. Если префикс к примеру будет 555 то условие \d{7} уже не сработает, как то надо на выходе +префикс неважно какой длины 2 или 3 иметь 9 цифр

Comment: разбейте свой массив на 2 части по длине префикса, и будет у вас `((11|22|33)\d{7})|((444|555|666)\d{6})` условно, если вы хотите известные префиксы в выражение вносить

Comment: А результирующую строку никак нельзя на длину проверить?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hoAMBh/1 такое что ли? для кодов 11 и 222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно использовать просмотры вперед. Сначала проверить, что впереди 9 цифр, а потом проверить коды.

```
^373(?=\d{9}$)(11|222)\d+$
```

- сначала проверяем что строка начинается с 373 (`^373`)
- затем используем позитивный просмотр вперед, в котором проверяем, что впереди 9 цифр , а затем конец строки `(?=\d{9}$)`
- потом проверяем собственно префиксы коды оператора, например `11|222`.
- далее сам номер определяют оставшиеся числа `\d+`.

https://regex101.com/r/hoAMBh/2

Comment: Супер! То что надо

Answer (score 0):

Ну так просто добавь к двухзначному ещё цифру:

```
^373(44\d|447)\d{6}$
```

Хотя конкретно в данном случае эта конструкция бесполезна, т. к. `447` очевидно является частным случаем для `44\d`.

Comment: Мне не очень подходит такое решение, так как у меня массив префиксов, к примеру 10 значений, для каждого сидеть прописывать длину как то не очень